# Accessing protected variable keys and values

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any way of accessing **hash** without a loop? If not, what are the other easiest ways? The variable is coming from Symfony2 `createQueryBuilder...->...->getResult();`

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($var);

Array
(
    [0] => User\RecordBundle\Entity\UserEntity Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 5
            [fullname:protected] => yoyo
            [email:protected] => yoyo@yoyo.com
            [username:protected] => yoyoyoy
            [password:protected] => 
            [confirmation:protected] => 
            [tc:protected] => 
            [hash:protected] => bb53ed2057d377bab37839ba0d66091ada5c525f
            [salt:protected] => aeff8de4e3a3b28412b27cb02932547ca7e56249
            [created:protected] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2014-06-10 21:29:59
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Ja
                )

            [updated:protected] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the class `UserEntity` has getters and setters defined for its properties so to access the property `hash` you would do something like

```
$userObject = $var[0];
$var[0]->getHash();
```

where `getHash()` is defined as

```
class UserEntity {

    protected $hash;

    public function getHash() {
        return $this->hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I missed to add zero after the variable. It is 00:04 here now so it is better to sleep I think! I'll accept it tomorrow. +1 though.